# visual studio .net 4.5 framework issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5

does anyone know how to add reference to .net 4.5 framework in visual studio 2010 project. 
I don't want to migrate to VS 2013 or 2015.

Some people claim it's possible, other say no.

Comment: Serious developers always upgrade as Microsoft requires. Don't play tricks, because that won't bring you any good.